# Change the /NA to special values in R

Tags: r

I have a data.table table with about 50,000 rows. There are two columns. There are lots of "/NA" in it.

Example:

```
  V1 V2
  A 1    
  B 2    
  A 1    
  C 3    
  A NA    
  B 2    
  C 3    
  A /NA    
  B /NA    
  A 1
```

I want to get

```
V1 V2        
 A 1    
 B 2    
 A 1    
 C 3    
 A 1    
 B 2    
 C 3    
 A 1    
 B 2    
 A 1
```

How can I finish it?

Thank you so much, Justin

Comment: how were you using ifelse?

Comment: "B" column? You do not have a B column. Do you mean 'V2' column?

Comment: Thank you for the questions:yes,it's "V2" column.And in fact the value of "V2" should be numbers(A is 1 , B is 2,C is 3) while it's not just the same as  "V1" column

Answer (score 0):

```
tf <- tempfile()
writeLines(" V1    V2  
  A     A   
            B     B                  
            A     A    
            C     C    
            A     NA    
            B     B    
            C     C    
            A    /NA    
            B    /NA    
            A    A", tf )

x <- read.table(tf, header=T, stringsAsFactors = F)
x$V2 <- ifelse(gsub("[/]","", x$V2) == "NA" | is.na(x$V2), x$V1, x$V2)

R> x
   V1 V2
1   A  A
2   B  B
3   A  A
4   C  C
5   A  A
6   B  B
7   C  C
8   A  A
9   B  B
10  A  A
```

#### edit

A second `ifelse()` clause (or `switch`) is needed for the new question to parse `V1` to `V2`. Note that I've switched the initial clause's evaluation via `!`:

```
x$V2 <- ifelse(!(gsub("[/]","", x$V2) == "NA" | is.na(x$V2)), x$V2, 
          ifelse(x$V1 == "A", 1, ifelse(x$V1 == "B", 2,3)))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.But my problem is that what would be the code if the second is "1,2,3..." but not "A,B,C...." just as my supplementary data?

Comment: You should **ask the question for which you want an answer.** I've answered your question, not read your mind that you want the answer to a different question.... Secondly, you haven't even tried this code on `1,2,3`. If you had, you'd have noticed that a very simple modification still works. Please put a modicum of effort into your own work.

Comment: Thank you @Alex.In fact I have tried your code:it's totally correct in my original question.I think it's my question that I haven't told the question clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the data frame in R to get the same result

`example <- data.frame(V1 = c("A","B","A","C","A","B","C","A","B","A"), 
                       V2=c(1,2,1,3,"NA",2,3,"/NA","/NA",1), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
example  <- within(example, V2[V1=="A" & (V2=="NA" | V2=="/NA")] <-1) 
example  <- within(example, V2[V1=="B" & (V2=="NA" | V2=="/NA")] <-2) 
example  <- within(example, V2[V1=="C" & (V2=="NA" | V2=="/NA")] <-3)`